# Aligning similar images with selected area from reference image

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, vision

I have 4 taken photo same object with different angles. And i can play orderly on imageview like gif. But i noticed i need to align (focus) images on one focus point. Some app can make that, but i cant find solution how can i do. I shared example video:

In this video, https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkHdC.jpg took 4 photo with camera, all images contain same objects, and user can choose align (focus) area with touches objects on images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Vision framework: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/aligning_similar_images

simon

Comment: Thanks you so much Simon.
I am looking and runing that code but i dont understand how can i align with focus point? If you see the video, you can choose focus point on ref image and all image align on that point. Could you please suggest solution?

Comment: Sorry, @Vileriu, I'm not too familiar with the Vision framework, I posted that link because it appeared to answer your question.